# How to prevent the user from going back to the login page after login in php?

Tags: php

I have a webpage using which the user logs-in and proceeds to the profile page. However, when the user presses the back button; the user can goto the previous page. I want to restrict the user or .. say I want to redirect the user to the index.php page. What should I do?

Currently, I am checking for the session variable which is mandatory; if the user has the session variable then the user will direcyly proceed to the profile page. However, the user is still able to go back to the login page after login. How can I avoid it?

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    // do some action  
} else{

echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'location.href="index.php"';
echo '</script>';

unset($_SESSION['id']);
session_destroy();  
}
```

Comment: I think this may be browser dependent. In some browsers, the back button doesn't reload from the server, so your PHP is not run again.

Comment: @Barmar I am using Mozilla for the time being. It redirects me to the previous page.

Comment: Why do you need to prevent the user from going back to the login page? Just prevent them from resubmitting the login.

Comment: The script that processes the login submission should check if they're already logged in, and disallow the login.

Comment: @Barmar I am login a user using Google login. So, I have a google logout button which unsets the token from the  session and redirects the user to the login page. However, the user can still go back to the profile page by pressing back button after logout. How should I avoid it?

Comment: It's just a cached copy of the old page. You can't stop a user from viewing something they already downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    //show login stuff
} else {
    //redirect back to an other page:
    header('location: index.php');
}
```

When using header('location... you must make sure no output is shown on the page.

Comment: If his Javascript solution isn't working, it probably means that the browser isn't fetching the page from the server. So your solution won't work any better.

Comment: header() redirects me to that page. However in the end its the same. The user gets redirected to the index.php page and user can press back button and goto profile.php page again. So, it wont work for me

Comment: @Barmar I dont have any javascript on my client-side. Do I need to disable back button? It sounds like a terrible idea to me

Comment: You can't disable the back button, it's a security feature.

Comment: Yes, just tested both the header function and Nevermore's javascript, both worked in my case. Something else must be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify by using a function or method in your class (very usefull if you have many pages). And just put it on every page you think required.

```
 class Logins{

            public function NeedLogin() { 

            if (isset($_SESSION['id'] === false) {
            session_destroy();
            header('Location:/login');
            exit();     
            }

        }

    public function NeedLogout() { 

            if (isset($_SESSION['id'] === true) {
            header('Location:/user'); // or any main protected pages
            exit();     
            }

        }

}// class

$log = new Logins();
```

Now, for every pages that required login, at the first line of every page you should put :

```
<?php $log->NeedLogin(); ?>
```

this method will protect users from accessing the protected or secure page if not yet logged in, and redirect to login page by header('Location:/login');

And for every general (not protected) pages, you should put :

```
<?php $log->NeedLogout(); ?>
```

It will protect users ( that already logged in) from accessing the not protected pages ( including login page), before users click logout button and destroy all session.

Comment: catching a PDOException is useless as nothing inside your `try` will throw one.

Comment: Sorry for that, just remove it. That's only in my personal case of my whole web structure. It should be not there included above. Thanks for commenting.